# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, или

Имеется побудительное предложение в составе сложного. Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "или" в таком предложении?
**Верни деньги или я за тобой приду!**

Я думаю, что не нужна, так как в побудительных сложносочиненных предложениях запятая не ставится. Но здесь — одно побудительное предложение.

Comment: Я думаю, что запятая НЕ НУЖНА.

Answer (score 2):

***Верни деньги, или я за тобой приду.***

Сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), первое предложение односоставное (побудительное, определенно-личное), второе предложение двусоставное.

Общих элементов нет, и нет возможности как-то объединить эти разноструктурные предложения.

Поэтому пауза делается и **запятая ставится** по общему правилу.

Что-то непонятно... Наверное, надо  процитировать Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении

1. Запятыми **разделяются предикативные части сложносочиненного предложения (простые предложения), между которыми стоят союзы:**

1) соединительные союзы [и, да (в значении и), ни…ни]:

2) противительные союзы [а, но, да (в значении но), однако, же, зато, а то, не то, а не то]:

**3) разделительные союзы (или,** либо, ли…или, ли…ли, то…то, то ли…то ли, не то…не то): **Уймись, или худо будет (П.); Он должен уехать, или я погибла!**

**Желательно запомнить следующее**: проблемы с постановкой запятой перед одиночными союзами ***И, ИЛИ***  в ССП бывают в двух случаях:

а) Если есть **общий элемент** (второстепенный член, вводное слово, бессоюзная связь и т.д.);

б) Если простые предложения являются **односоставными** одного вида.

Во всех остальных случаях **запятая ставится**.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая **нужна**, поскольку союз *или* выступает здесь как *противительный* (противопоставляя второе высказывание первому) и заменяется на "иначе" или "в противном случае" (в обоих случаях замены необходимость запятой становится очевидной).

Comment: 1) Союз ИЛИ разделительный, по определению он обозначает взаимоисключение вариантов, выбор одного из них. 2) Среди противительных союзов нет союза ИЛИ. 3) И зачем ему быть противительным, разве перед разделительным союзом не ставится запятая?

Comment: @Alex_ander Союз "или" — разве противительный? Разделительные союзы — значение: «или это, или то».

Comment: **Иначе** - противительный союз: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/823750 Здесь "или" выполняет _в точности такую же_ функцию, как бы его ни классифицировали в классификациях. Я сослался на _определение противительного союза_: https://all_words.academic.ru/76075/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Иначе, а то, не то - это частные случаи разделительных отношений, альтернативная мотивация, ультимативное условие, но только не противительные отношения. С другой стороны, какой смысл уточнять значение союза, разве это влияет на постановку запятой? Какой бы ни был союз, запятая все рано ставится, или это не так? (И у Розенталя союз ИЛИ в таких же ситуациях назван разделительным, запятая ставится).

Comment: Я воспользовался терминологией Ушакова ("иначе - противительный союз"), который проиллюстрировал словарную статью (п.2, где "иначе" выступает как союз, см. ссылку выше) примером, весьма близким к нашему. "Смысл" же обращения к _значению_ союза (или = иначе) уже в том, что в практической ситуации (напр. срочное составление лаконичного ультимативного письма грамотному человеку) правильное решение о запятой находится без необходимости анализа совокупности правил и оговорок к ним.

Comment: Alex_ander, ваш грамотный человек ведет себя странно. Он нарушает основное правило Розенталя о постановке запятой в сложном предложении (непостановка запятой в особых случаях для особых союзов - это всего лишь частный вариант правила). Почему-то он вспоминает Ушакова (годы жизни 1873 - 1942, составление словаря 1934 - 1940, а это всё было до 1956 года, а сейчас-то 2019 год!). И почему свое решение, в котором нарушено именно основное правило,  а вовсе не "совокупность правил и оговорок к ним", он считает верным? Что верного и правильного в таком поступке?

Comment: "Грамотный человек" здесь - получатель письма. Присутствие запятой от терминологии (не будем ссорить Розенталя с Ушаковым) не зависит: достаточно заменить одно слово на другое и увидеть Её. Главное, что есть короткий путь, а само предложение требуется только в ситуации, когда нет под рукой томов или нет времени для упорядочивания хаоса в запомненных правилах.

Comment: Ну ладно, мы друг друг не слышим. В заключение нашей беседы я хотела бы только напомнить о том, что когда детки где-то в классе втором проходят сложное предложение, им говорят, что в таком предложении ставится ...ЗАПЯТАЯ. И больше пока ничего не говорят. И еще мое личное наблюдение. Почему-то чем дольше вы отстаиваете свою весьма сомнительную точку зрения, тем больше вызываете у меня интереса и даже уважения. Правда, где-то начиная только  с определенного момента. Парадокс, загадка для психологии!